# Python subprocess: Start a process with a `stdin` that doesn't close

Tags: python, subprocess

I'd like to start a new process using the `subprocess` module. I'd like the `stdin` to be a stream that never sends anything but also doesn't terminate. Basically the same kind of input stream that a program would get if I were to launch it in the shell and not type anything, ever. Is that possible?

Comment: If you use `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and then never write to it or close it, well, there you are. Are you trying to also use `communicate()`, or otherwise doing something that would make this more difficult or complicated? (That is, can you explain enough of where the specific difficulty you're encountering is that we understand why there's a question being asked in the first place?)

Comment: ...that said, what you get when you "launch [something] in a shell" is a TTY, which is a different matter. Do you *really* need one, or do you just need stdin to be, as you first said, "a stdin that doesn't close"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` to the `Popen` constructor, and then avoid doing anything -- like calling `communicate()` -- which would later close that FIFO.